# $parent not working in ng-include angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am changing value of variable inside child controller using `$scope.$parent` but change is not reflecting to its parent.

```
<div data-ng-if="!addBillDetails">
    <button class="btn btn-small" data-ng-if="trItem.skuId==217"
            data-ng-click="addDetails()">Add Details</button>
</div>
<div data-ng-if="addBillDetails" data-ng-include="'views/test.html'"></div>
```

```
$scope.addDetails=function(){
                $scope.addBillDetails=true;
};
```

test.html and testCrl

```
<div data-ng-controller="testCtrl">
<button type="button" class="btn red" data-ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
$scope.cancel=function(){
   alert("cancel");
  $scope.$parent.addBillDetails=false;
};
```

Comment: try without $parent!

Comment: `ng-include` creates a child scope.

Comment: $parent can access parent scope right???

Comment: Yes but there is now another parent in the hierarchy due to the `ng-include` child scope. So it would be `$parent.$parent` which is ugly. Use an object as suggested below

Comment: @charlietfl I feel `controllerAs` is better way to go, behind the scenes it uses implicit `dot rule` :p

Comment: @Keshav can you please check the below answer, hope it will help you. Thanks

Comment: I have done it by creating a method in parent scope that changes the value.Thanks a lot for your precious time. @Pankaj

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because `ng-include`/`ng-if` creates a prototypically inherited child scope.

Let's begin with why `$parent` trick didn't work for you, basically `addBillDetails` variable wasn't allocated in immediate `$parent` scope of `testCtrl`. Since `views/test.html` template gets rendered based on `ng-if` & `ng-include` directive combination. It creates different scope hierarchy, refer below diagram.

```
//ng-controller="parentCtrl" `$scope.addBillDetails`
|
|
ng-if
   |
   |- ng-inlcude
      |
      |- ng-controller="testCtrl" ($scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.addBillDetails)
```

By looking at above diagram, if you want to modify `addBillDetails` of parent `testCtrl`, the you have to use `$scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.addBillDetails` in order to get hold of correct value. Check [**demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MBRWFRgLCHycIjB9geWG?p=preview). *Never use `$parent` in your code, that makes your code tightly couple html design & assumption.*

---

In such cases using object (reference type variable) are preferred or using `controllerAs` pattern while using controller ( [**controllerAs version**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mqmXHxUVHU9C3xTRQOdP?p=preview)).

Recommend to read on [**"What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?"**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/2435473)

**Html**

```
{{model.addBillDetails}}
  <div data-ng-if="!model.addBillDetails">
    <button class="btn btn-small" data-ng-if="trItem.skuId==217" data-ng-click="addDetails()">Add Details</button>
  </div>
  <div data-ng-if="model.addBillDetails" data-ng-include="'views/test.html'"></div>
```

**Code**

```
.controller('parentCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.model.addBillDetails = true;
    $scope.addDetails = function() {
      $scope.model.addBillDetails = true;
    };
})
.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cancel = function() {
      alert("cancel");
      $scope.model.addBillDetails = false;
    };
})
```

[**Preview**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DCIT6N2bjMc1x8JPjMVn?p=preview)

Comment: `$scope.addBillDetails = true;` needs model object update

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for heads up mate, I updated answer :)